# Formatação de gráficos no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Como fazer para que quando eu pegue a informação de um servidor usando mysql, essa informação apareça na planilha com gráfico já formatado no excel?

Answer (score 0):

1º Você precisa definir uma área no excel para os dados que serão utilizados como fonte para o gráfico;

2º Você precisa criar um Módulo no VBA que conecta com o banco MySQL, faz o select dos dados que você quer no gráfico e plota o resultado deste select na área de dados do gráfico reservada no excel.

3º Sempre que você executar a macro que faz o select no MySQL, os dados serão atualizados no excel.

Exemplo: você cria um gráfico no excel e define que a área de dados do gráfico será da célula A1 até D1000, depois quando você popular essas células com os dados que você vai trazer do banco de dados, o gráfico será atualizado também.

Comment: Mas tem que ser na mesma planilha?

Comment: Normalmente sim, pode colocar em outra aba, se não quiser que fique na mesma aba do gráfico.